# Swift: iterate using Index and Element

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I want to implement function in Swift similar to default `find`, but which accept comparator:

```
func find<C : CollectionType>(domain: C, comparator: (C.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> C.Index? {
    for (index, element) in enumerate(domain) {
        if comparator(element) {
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

The problem that `enumerate` returns tuple of type `(Int, C.Generator.Element)`, while i need `(C.Index, C.Generator.Element)`. I have searched much, but didn't find how to iterate using `C.Index` type.

**Edit.**

Sorry, it was a typo. I mean `enumerate` instead of `generate`

Comment: you mean `enumerate` not `generate`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Airspeed Velocity notes, I assume you mean `enumerate` here rather than `generate`. The tool you want, however, is `indices` to get all the indices of the collection:

```
func find<C : CollectionType>(domain: C, comparator: (C.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> C.Index? {
    for index in indices(domain) {
        if comparator(domain[index]) {
            return index
        }
    }    
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to use `indices` rather than `enumerate`, then use subscript to fetch the value:

```
func find<C : CollectionType>(domain: C, comparator: (C.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> C.Index? {
    for index in indices(domain) {
        if comparator(domain[index]) {
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

but I'm guessing you already knew that and wanted a solution that got you both the element and the index together without needing subscript.  You could use `Zip2` to do this:

```
func find<C : CollectionType>(domain: C, comparator: (C.Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> C.Index? {
    for (index, element) in Zip2(indices(domain), domain) {
        if comparator(element) {
            return index
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

edit: as Rob points out below, this is guaranteed to work per the swift docs.

*However* this relies on something that makes me slightly uneasy, which is assuming that iterating over a collection via it's generator is guaranteed to return values in the same order as they are indexed.  It would possibly be a slightly obnoxious thing for a collection to not do this (and since most collections use `IndexingGenerator` to serve up their generators, it's very likely to be the case).  But I don't think it's documented as a guarantee so could be considered iffy.

Comment: I believe this is documented adequately in the definition of `CollectionType`: The sequence view of the elements is identical to the collection view.  In other words, the following code binds the same series of values to `x` as does `for x in self {}`::

///   for i in startIndex..<endIndex {
///     let x = self[i]
///   }

Comment: aha you're right, in which case I retract my unease and decide I like this solution :)

Comment: Glad you used the moment to teach Zip2. So powerful, so little-explored.

Comment: what do you know, two Zip2 answers in one day